# Subset of dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a python dictionary of the form `{'ip1:port1' : <value>, 'ip1:port2' : <value>, 'ip2:port1' : <value>, ...}`. Dictionary keys are strings, consisting of ip:port pairs. Values are not important for this task.

I need a list of `ip:port` combinations with unique IP addresses, ports can be any of those that appear among original keys. For example above, two variants are acceptable: `['ip1:port1', ip2:port1']` and `['ip1:port2', ip2:port1']`.

What is the most pythonic way for doing it?

Currently my solution is

```
def get_uniq_worker_ips(workers):
    wip = set(w.split(':')[0] for w in workers.iterkeys())
    return [[worker for worker in workers.iterkeys() if worker.startswith(w)][0] for w in wip]
```

I don't like it, because it creates additional lists and then discards them.

Comment: So then use genexs instead.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific?

Comment: by "genexs", I think he means "generator expressions", which essentially means you create a generator instead of a list. This could be done by changing out the square brackets `[]` with parantheses `()` in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group by same IP addresses:

```
data = {'ip1:port1' : "value1", 'ip1:port2' : "value2", 'ip2:port1' : "value3", 'ip2:port2': "value4"}
by_ip = {k: list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda s: s.split(":")[0])}
by_ip
# {'ip1': ['ip1:port1', 'ip1:port2'], 'ip2': ['ip2:port1', 'ip2:port2']}
```

Then just pick any one from the different groups of IPs.

```
{v[0]: data[v[0]] for v in by_ip.values()}
# {'ip1:port1': 'value1', 'ip2:port1': 'value3'}
```

Or shorter, making a generator expression for just the first key from the groups:

```
one_by_ip = (next(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda s: s.split(":")[0]))
{key: data[key] for key in one_by_ip}
# {'ip1:port1': 'value1', 'ip2:port1': 'value3'}
```

However, note that `groupby` requires the input data to be sorted. So if you want to avoid sorting all the keys in the dict, you should instead just use a `set` of already seen keys.

```
seen = set()
not_seen = lambda x: not(x in seen or seen.add(x))
{key: data[key] for key in data if not_seen(key.split(":")[0])}
# {'ip1:port1': 'value1', 'ip2:port1': 'value3'}
```

This is similar to your solution, but instead of looping the unique keys and finding a matching key in the dict for each, you loop the keys and check whether you've already seen the IP.

Comment: Note that the OP asked for a list of keys, not a dict. Even though I love groupby, I prefer your 2nd solution since it avoids the O(nlogn) sort.

Comment: @PM2Ring Right, but that will make the last step(s) just easier. I agree that the `set` solution is probably best, requiring the least time and space. `groupby` was just the first thing I thought off and I did not want to remove it after it had a few upvotes.

Comment: Fair enough. And I certainly agree that you shouldn't remove code from an answer that's already received upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to transform your keys into a custom class that only looks at the IP part of the string when doing an equality test. It also needs to supply an appropriate `__hash__` method.

The logic here is that the `set` constructor will "see" keys with the same IP as identical, ignoring the port part in the comparison, so it will avoid adding a key to the set if a key with that IP is already present in the set.

Here's some code that runs on Python 2 or Python 3.

```
class IPKey(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.key = s
        self.ip, self.port = s.split(':', 1)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.ip == other.ip

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.ip)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'IPKey({}:{})'.format(self.ip, self.port)

def get_uniq_worker_ips(workers):
    return [k.key for k in set(IPKey(k) for k in workers)]

# Test

workers = {
    'ip1:port1' : "val", 
    'ip1:port2' : "val", 
    'ip2:port1' : "val", 
    'ip2:port2' : "val", 
}

print(get_uniq_worker_ips(workers))
```

**output**

```
['ip2:port1', 'ip1:port1']
```

If you are running Python 2.7 or later, the function can use a set comprehension instead of that generator expression inside the `set()` constructor call.

```
def get_uniq_worker_ips(workers):
    return [k.key for k in {IPKey(k) for k in workers}]
```

The `IPKey.__repr__` method isn't strictly necessary, but I like to give all my classes a `__repr__` since it can be handy during development.

---

Here's a much more succinct solution which is very efficient, courtesy of [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements). It builds the desired list via a dictionary comprehension.

```
def get_uniq_worker_ips(workers):
    return list({k.partition(':')[0]:k for k in workers}.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed few characters in my solution and now am satisfied with it.

```
def get_uniq_worker_ips(workers):
    wip = set(w.split(':')[0] for w in workers.iterkeys())
    return [next(worker for worker in workers.iterkeys() if worker.startswith(w)) for w in wip]
```

Thanks to @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and @M.T. for explanations.

Comment: Note that this has quadratic complexity, i.e. O(n²) for finding the `next` matching entry for each of the unique IPs. Also, `startswith` will fail if you have, e.g.,  IPs `1.1.1.1` and `1.1.1.11`.

Comment: @tobias_k, I cannot understand why the complexity is quadratic. Outer loop is over `set` elements... Do you mean that inner loop will iterate all keys and create generator only after that iteration completes?

Comment: If k is the number of unique IP addresses and n the number of entries in the dict, then the complexity is k*n, which is, granted, not exactly quadratic (at least if k << n), but still much higher than necessary.